# Minimum number of maps such that their product is identically zero

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have a problem that I translated into set theory notation as best I could: let $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $C=\binom{S}{4}$, the set of 4-combinations from the set $S$, and let $\Pi=\{\pi:S\to\{-1,1\}\}$. Finally, define $\phi_{\pi}(\{s_{i_1},\dots,s_{i_4}\})=\sum\limits_{j=1}^4 \pi(s_{i_j})$. What is the minimum $m$ such that $\exists\pi_1,\dots,\pi_m\in\Pi:\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \phi_{\pi_j}$ is identically zero on $C$?

For example, if $n=8$, we can choose (abusing some notation) $\pi_1:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)\to(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)$, $\pi_2:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)\to(1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1)$, $\pi_3:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)\to(1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1)$ and then $\prod\limits_{j=1}^3 \phi_{\pi_j}$ is identically zero.

This feels like the kind of question that would be studied, despite the notation-heavy construction of the question I've provided here. Is there any literature on this? We can replace 4 with any even $k$ for a more general question. The heart of the question is finding a minimum set of maps of a certain type that spans all the possible zeros.

Comment: what is $\pi_j$??

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo $\pi_j$ is an arbitrary member of $\{\pi:S\to\{-1,1\}\}$.

Comment: I think you can have a simpler formulation: You have a set $S$ of $n$ elements, and $m$ subsets $\{\pi_i\}$ of $S$. What is the minimum $m$ such that, for every 4-combination of $S$, there exists a subset $\pi_i$ which contains exactly two of its elements. My first approach would probably be through graph theory: build a bipartite graph with one partition being the elements of $S$, the other - its subsets. Then you want every four nodes in the first partition to have two with a common neighbor, that isn't also neighbor of the other two...

Comment: By solving @TodorMarkov's reformulation as a set covering problem, I get the following values for $n\in\{4,\dots,13\}$: $1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6$

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you are asking for the minimal $m$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^m\phi_{\pi_j}=0$ for *any* choice of (distinct) $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_m\in\Pi$, or whether you are asking for the minimal $m$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^m\phi_{\pi_j}=0$ for *some* choice of (distinct) $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_m\in\Pi$. I suspect the latter, but could you make this explicit in the question?

Comment: @Servaes you're correct, I've edited to remove ambiguity

Comment: @TodorMarkov it's it ok to assume that, $\forall \pi_i: |\pi_i|=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ ? By symmetry of $\pi_i$ and its set complement, I intuitively feel like this is an ok assumption to make but I don't know how to make it rigorous

Comment: @PedroBach Your complement argument shows that there exists a such a collection $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_m$ with $m$ minimal with $|\pi_i|\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ for all $i$. However, enlarging any particular set $\pi_i$ to get equality does not preserve the desired property in general, so an argument or construction is needed to show that one can assume that $|\pi_i|=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ for all $i$, if it is true to begin with.

Comment: @PedroBach you cannot restrict to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.  For $n=9$, the minimum is $4$ without the restriction but $5$ with the restriction.

Comment: @RobPratt thanks, yeah I just came to the same conclusion. How are you making the graph for the set covering problem? in Matlab it takes a few minutes to make the proper edges (I think the major bottleneck is running the intersection() function so many times)

Comment: @PedroBach I am using the modeling language and mixed integer linear programming solver available in the OPTMODEL procedure in SAS.

Comment: @RobPratt OK, but how are you making A? That's the step that's taking the longest (equivalent to defining edges of the bipartite graph)

Comment: @PedroBach I provided the SAS code just now.  Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the OPTMODEL procedure in SAS to solve an integer linear programming formulation of the set covering problem.  Note the use of the BAND "bitwise and" function to extract the elements from each integer.

```
proc optmodel;
   num n = 8;
   num k = 4;
   set ELEMENTS = 0..n-1;
   set SUBSETS = 0..2^n-1;
   set ELEMENTS_s {s in SUBSETS} = {i in ELEMENTS: band(s,2^i)};
   set KSUBSETS = {s in SUBSETS: card(ELEMENTS_s[s]) = k};

   var Select {SUBSETS} binary;

   min NumSelected = sum {s in SUBSETS} Select[s];

   con Cover {t in KSUBSETS}:
      sum {s in SUBSETS: card(ELEMENTS_s[s] inter ELEMENTS_s[t]) = 2} Select[s] >= 1;

   solve;
   for {s in SUBSETS: Select[s].sol > 0.5} put ELEMENTS_s[s]=;
quit;
```

For $n=8$, the solver immediately returns an optimal solution with three subsets:
$\{0,2,6,7\},
\{1,4,6,7\},
\{3,5,6,7\}$

For $n=11$, here's an optimal solution with five subsets:
$\{1,5,7,10\},
\{0,1,4,6,8,10\},
\{1,2,3,9,10\},
\{0,1,5,6,7,9,10\},
\{1,4,5,7,8,9,10\}$

And another one with five subsets, each with five elements:
$\{0,1,2,3,4\},
\{0,1,2,3,6\},
\{0,1,5,6,7\},
\{2,3,5,6,8\},
\{2,3,5,8,9\},
\{0,1,8,9,10\}$

Comment: I'm not super familiar with SAS and the documentation is proving rather opaque. Can you explain what the line

set ELEMENTS_s {s in SUBSETS} = {i in ELEMENTS: band(s,2^i)};

is doing?

Comment: That line declares, for each integer $s\in\{0,1,\dots,2^n-1\}$, the subset of elements $i\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ such that the bitwise AND of $s$ and $2^i$ is positive.  For example, $s=22$ has binary representation $10110$, so $\text{ELEMENTS_s}[6] = \{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: Typo: change $6$ to $22$ in my last comment.

Comment: Thank you! And what is the Select[s] doing? I don't understand the declaration but I gather that it's used to create something that sum can iterate over?

Comment: The VAR statement declares a binary decision variable called Select[s] for each subset s.  The interpretation is that Select[s] is 1 if subset s is selected and is 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks again! I think Matlab's MILP solver is not very efficient compared to SAS - even after 1 hour of running, I was not able to come up with anything better than using 6 for the case n=11. Can you tell me your solution for n=11?

Comment: @PedroBach I added two optimal solutions for $n=11$ just now.